# Modify the column of a text file

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to change the second column of a text file,named as subject.txt, containing "1" and "2" to "0" and "1" using bash. Any suggestion? I am new to bash and any help would appreciate it.

```
Subj1  1
Subj2  2
Subj3  1
```

I would like to change it to:

```
Subj1  0
Subj2  1
Subj3  0
```

Comment: Sample file?  Any attempts? It's a trivial exercise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`:

```
cat subject.txt | awk '{ $2=$2-1; print $1"  "$2 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

restrict modifications only for 1 and 2

```
$ awk '$2==1 || $2==2 {$2--}1' file
```